# Flume: Directory to Avro -> Avro to HDFS - Not valid avro after transfer

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume, avro

I have users writing AVRO files and I want to use Flume to move all those files into HDFS using Flume. So I can later use Hive or Pig to query/analyse the data.

On the client I installed flume and have a SpoolDir source and AVRO sink like this:

```
a1.sources = src1
a1.sinks = sink1
a1.channels = c1

a1.channels.c1.type = memory

a1.sources.src1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.src1.channels = c1
a1.sources.src1.spoolDir = {directory}
a1.sources.src1.fileHeader = true
a1.sources.src1.deserializer = avro

a1.sinks.sink1.type = avro
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.sink1.hostname = {IP}
a1.sinks.sink1.port = 41414
```

On the hadoop cluster I have this AVRO source and HDFS sink:

```
a1.sources = avro1
a1.sinks = sink1
a1.channels = c1

a1.channels.c1.type = memory

a1.sources.avro1.type = avro
a1.sources.avro1.channels = c1
a1.sources.avro1.bind = 0.0.0.0
a1.sources.avro1.port = 41414

a1.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = {hdfs dir}
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .avro
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
a1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
```

The problem is that the files on HDFS are not valid AVRO files! I am using the hue UI to check whenever the file is a valid AVRO file or not. If I upload an AVRO I file that I generate on my pc to the cluster I can see its contents fine. But the files from flume are not valid AVRO files.

I tried the flume avro client that is included in flume but didn't work because it sends an flume event per line breaking the avro files, that is fixed with the `spooldir` source using `deserializer = avro`. So I think the problem is on the HDFS sink when is writing the files.

Using `hdfs.fileType = DataStream` it writes the values from the avro fields not the whole avro file, losing all the schema information. If I use `hdfs.fileType = SequenceFile` the files are not valid for some reason.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add this to your hdfs sink configuration (value of this property is by default `TEXT`):

```
a1.sinks.sink1.serializer = avro_event
```

This should write valid avro files, but with the default schema.

However, since your were using avro files as your input, you probably want to write avro files with the same schema. For that you can use the [AvroEventSerializer](https://github.com/cloudera/cdk/blob/master/cdk-flume-avro-event-serializer/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/serialization/AvroEventSerializer.java) from [cloudera's cdk](https://github.com/cloudera/cdk). Assuming you built the code and placed the jar in flume's `lib` directory, you can now define the Serializer in the properties file:

```
a1.sinks.sink1.serializer = org.apache.flume.serialization.AvroEventSerializer$Builder
```

The serializer assumes that the avro schema is present the header of every event, either as a URL or as a LITERAL. To use the latter approach (that is less efficient, but might be easier to try out), you must tell your source on the client side to add the schema literal to every event, by adding this property:

```
a1.sources.src1.deserializer.schemaType = LITERAL
```